# Variable argument command

Tags: macros

I'm typesetting some group theory notes, and a significant amount of it is cycles, i.e. `\left(1\,2\,3\right)`. Is there a way of defining a command which takes a arbitrary number of arguments so I can write `\cycle{1}{2}{3}`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a comma-separated list to define your cycle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{listcount}\newcounter{totalcount}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\cycle}[1]{%
  \setcounter{totalcount}{0}% Reset total count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{totalcount}}% Reconfigure count
  \docsvlist{#1}% Count number of items
  \setcounter{listcount}{0}% Reset current item count
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% Reconfigure item \do
    \stepcounter{listcount}% Next item
    ##1\ifnum\value{listcount}<\value{totalcount}\,\fi% Print item
  }
  \left(\docsvlist{#1}\right)% Process list
}
\begin{document}
\[ \cycle{1} \quad \cycle{1,2,3} \quad \cycle{1,1,2,3,5,8,13} \]
\end{document}
```

The command `\do` is redefined twice inside `\cycle`. The first time is for counting the number of items supplied, while the second time is for printing all the items.

Answer (score 11):

A comma separated list notation is really recommended.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cycle}{m}{\cycle_main:n {#1}}

\seq_new:N \l_cycle_body_seq
\cs_new:Npn \cycle_main:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_cycle_body_seq {,} { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_cycle_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_cycle_body_seq { ##1 \, }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If *really* `\left` and `\right` are needed, which I don't believe as the argument should always be a list of numbers, then change the definition of `\cycle` into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\cycle}{ s O{} m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\left(}{\mathopen{#2(}}
  \cycle_main:n { #3 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\right)}{\mathclose{#2)}}
 }
```

that will allow a commonly used "fence" notation:

- `\cycle{1,2,3}` for normal size parentheses
- `\cicle[\big]{1,2,3}` for larger parentheses (any size prescribing command can be used
- `\cycle*{1,2,3}` to enclose into `\left(` and `\right)`.